# html along with java script is not loading properly by router.navigateByUrl() method from angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am redirecting new html page from angular .ts file by

this.router.navigateByUrl('/senderReciverCombo');

The html file along with some java script code loading but not functioning as suppose to after redirecting, but its functioning proper after refreshing page